# Autocomplete Jquery with user restriction

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on auto complete and used this http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

Now my query is that this api gives the user a flexibility to type and search the values of combo-box but due to this user can type anything.But is there any way to restrict the user from submitting wrong search query. This is because my combo-box is going to be used as a search criteria and its value is submitted to next page and due to this feature it submits wrong data to the page.

Thank you in advance...
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a custom matcher function to force a match or clear the field...

```
$("#input").autocomplete({ << initialise the autocomplete here >>})
.on('blur', function(event){
  // Grab the autocomplete object
  var autocomplete = $(this).data("autocomplete");
  var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i");
  // Iterate through the autocomplete list items to find any partial or full matches
  autocomplete.widget().children(".ui-menu-item").each(function() {
    var item = $(this).data("item.autocomplete");
    if (matcher.test(item.value || item)) {
      //There was a match
      matchcount++;
      autocomplete.selectedItem = item;
      return;
    }
  });
  if (autocomplete.selectedItem) {
    //if there was a match trigger the select event on that match
    autocomplete._trigger("select", event, {
      item: autocomplete.selectedItem
    });
  //there was no match, clear the input
  } else {
      $(this).val('');
  }
});
```

Comment: can you implement on JSfiddle..and I am not getting $("#input").autocomplete({ << initialise the autocomplete here >>})
what to initialize here?

Comment: Maybe this is a clearer/easier answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909077/jquery-ui-autocomplete-disallow-free-text-entry