# Restrict user to select from auto suggested list only in textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a texbox which has auto suggestion option while typing. I want to restrict  user to select option from the suggested  list only. currently auto suggestion list appear but user can enter and select his own option. any help please.

```
jQuery().ready(function() {
    jQuery("#ingr").autocomplete("<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/grocery/autocomplete.php", {
        width: 260,
        matchContains: true,

    });
});
```

Comment: use Select Option   http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_value.asp

Comment: when the user have selected the option, make the textbox `disabled`

Comment: This has already been asked previously : 

[Link to prev asked question in StackOverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909077/jquery-ui-autocomplete-disallow-free-text-entry